# Adding multiple hard drives to ubuntu server so owncloud can use them

Tags: server

I am using an old desktop to install ubuntu server on. Once I have it installed, I upgrade to the newest version. After it is finished, I install owncloud. I've gotten it all set up and working. The problem is I have four internal hard drives (one which has the OS and everything on) and an external hard drive. Ubuntu server detects them but I can't use them in owncloud as storage. I add external storage support to owncloud and set up the devices using local, it even has the green light letting me know they are found. But when I go back to the main page, I still only have my main hard drive. How do I get owncloud to use these other drives as storage? I'm at my wit's end, I've installed Ubuntu Server at least 12 times.

So I've used LVM to set up three of my four internal hard drives to act as one (saving the last one for when I build a website). Then I installed owncloud. Owncloud reads the LVM as the default filesystem. I have an external USB 3TB hard drive. How should I format this to be used on owncloud? I've read using GBT because it has support for >2TB, but would it be able to be used by Linux and Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the folder's that you like to bind in owncloud is accessible for the user witch run apache2 or your webserver. When you run apache2 then the group and the user is www-data.

When you use the folder only for owncloud:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/your/external/folder
```

When you use the folders for owncloud and other stuff:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /path/to/your/external/folder
sudo chmod -R g+w /path/to/your/external/folder
```

Comment: I did that in a previous installation, but nothing happened. I'm guessing that my other drives weren't mounted to a directory because they were still being called /dev/sda, /dev/sdb, and so on. As of right now, I found a guide using LVM to set up the first hard drive, then after installation is complete, going through and connecting the other drives. We'll see how this goes.

Comment: You could solve the problem? How look your setup?